# How to secure Node-RED http in nodes

Tags: node-red

I created a Node-RED starter kit and bound a Cloudant instance to it.

How can I implement HTTP Node security on the IBM Cloud as described here:

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red

I don‘t have a local instance, where can I find the .settings.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Node-RED starter kit includes a file called `bluemix-settings.js` - that is the settings file you should edit to modify your Node-RED configuration.

You can edit it using the Deployment Pipeline. A basic outline for doing that is included in [this](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-node-red-starter-application/#step-6-add-extra-nodes-to-your-node-red-palette) guide. It describes how to add extra nodes by editing `package.json`. You can follow the same steps to edit `bluemix-settings.js`.